# regex for php to find all self-closing tags

Tags: php, xhtml, preg-match, domdocument

I've got a system that uses a DomDocumentFragment which is created based on markup from a database or another area of the system (i.e. other XHTML code).

One such tag that may be included is:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Before the string is added to the DomDocumentFragment, the content is correct - the  class is closing correctly.

However, the DomDocumentFragment transforms this into:

```
<div class="clear"/>
```

This does not display correctly in browsers due to the incorrect closing of the  tag.

So my thought is to post-process the XML string that the DomDocument returns me (that includes the incorrect div structure, as shown above), and transform self-closing tags back to their correct structure... i.e. turn  back to .

But I'm having trouble with the pattern for preg_match to find these tags - I've seen some patterns that return all tags (i.e. find all  tags), but not just those that are self closing.

I've tried something along the lines of this, but my head gets a little confused with regex (and I start over-complicating things)

```
/<div(["\d\w\s])\/>/
```

The aim is for a pattern to match , where the "...." could be any valid XHTML attributes.

Any suggestions or pointers to put me back on track?

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1):

Limit the problem domain -- you need to change `<div class="clear"/>` to `<div class="clear"></div>` ... so search for the former, and replace it with the latter using a straightforward find and replace operation.  It *should* be faster and it will **definitely** be safer

Whatever you do, do *not* try to [parse HTML with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) (which you're trying to do by building a regex that can detect a `<div>` with arbitrary attributes.)

Comment: Thanks Sean... I think I was aiming for a "catch-all" solution in case other invalid closings appear too (i.e. <script.../>, etc). 

But best just to use str_replace instead, and be more specific in the searches?

Comment: @Marty - When trying to deal with HTML, there are three ways to go about it: `str_replace`, limited regular expressions, and DOM parsers.  When dealing with a simple problem, str_replace or regexes are your friends -- anything where you need to say "tag" or "attribute" probably needs a DOM parser (to ensure that you are *actually* dealing with a tag or attribute.)

Comment: You might also want to check the documentation for `DomDocumentFragment` to determine if there is a way you can stop it from updating your `<div>` s in the first place :-)

Comment: Thanks - I'll hard-code that case in for the moment and investigate later for a better "catch all" solution - all I can think of at the moment is the "clear" example so will run with that. I've looked into the DOM classes within PHP and it's an issue there with this behaviour - saveHTML creates HTML, but not XHTML, while saveXML creates XML, but features self-closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Putting

```
<div></div>
```

into a DomDocumentFragment doesn't actually change it into

```
<div/>
```

it changes it into

```
A-DOM-Element-Node-with-name-"div"-and-no-content.
```

It's only when the DomDocumentFragment is *serialized* that either `<div></div>` or `<div/>` is created. In other words, the problem lies not with the DomDocumentFragment, but with the serialization process that you are using.

PHP is not my language, so I can't be much more help, but I would be looking for an HTML-compatible serializer for your DomDocumentFragment, rather than try to patch the output after serialization.

Comment: PHP's downfall here - there's a HTML-compatible function, but not a XHTML-compatible function. Maybe in the future... if I set the "div" to have a single space character, i.e. <div class="clear"> </div>, it actually works correctly. Thanks for your input - I've seen a few others who have ideas about a serializer, so will add it to my to-do list.